# Can't connect to a MySQL from the command line (works from MySQL Workbench)

Tags: mysql

I am connected through a local socket/pipe and the username password is root/roots. I can login and view the 4 schemas I have created. However, when I use the `mysql` command at the command line and login to localhost then the only schemas visible are `test` and `information_schema`.  What am I doing wrong and how to I login correctly?

Comment: Are you connecting as the same user?

Answer (score 2):

As 'ypercube' commented, log in from both connections to tell which user is connecting. You should see differences when you run SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER(); and SHOW GRANTS;

You are logging in but you will need to GRANT permissions (from your root account) to your @'localhost' account to gain access to your four schemas. (ref. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html)

If this is not being used for testing, it would be adviseable to secure/drop anonymous accounts that are typically set-up with MySql if you don't intend to use them. (ref. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/default-privileges.html)